# Concatenating row values in Athena Aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I've 2 cols lets say id and values. I want to concatenate values grouped by id col.
for eg.
I've
ID  Values
1    a
1    b
2    a
2    b
I need the output as
ID   Values
1    a,b
2    a,b

Comment: Hi Muralidhar, welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 15):

You can use an `array_agg` followed by an `array_join`

```
select id, array_join(array_agg(values),',') from table group by 1
```

The `array_agg` will give you an array of all values with the same id, and the `array_join` will concatenate them into a string. See [the docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html).