# How to concatenate multiple cell data into a single cell based on condition using SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, amazon-athena, string-concatenation

New to using SQL here. I use Amazon Athena.

For example, say I have a table, **customer_svc**, of customers and the services they've subscribed to as follows:

| customer | service |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | A |
| Alex | B |
| Alex | C |
| Dave | A |
| Dave | D |

I need to design a query to concatenate the services for each unique customer into a single string as follows:

| customer | services |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | A, B, C |
| Dave | A, D |

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Amazon Athena - Concatenating Strings and Arrays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/concatenating-strings-and-arrays.html)

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943888/concatenating-row-values-in-athena-aws

Comment: Thank you so much @VirussInside. That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in Amazon Athena / S3 :

**Dataset used for the query exmaple**

[image: CSV data for example]

**Query**

```
select customer, array_join(array_agg(service),',') as services from customer_svc group by customer
```

**Results**

[image: Query results example]

[Arrays documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html)

[Amazon Athena Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/concatenating-strings-and-arrays.html)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.